# Hudson CI: Job waits until all of its dependency jobs are done

Tags: hudson

I have a bunch of jobs of which some of them can run parallel. However I also have a consolidation job which has to wait until all of the parallel jobs are completed and perform the consolidation.

Eg: 
Job A -> Job B, Job C
Job B -> Job D, Job E
Job C -> Job F
Job F, Job E -> Job G

After Job A is done, Job B and Job C are to be triggered. Job D & Job E will be triggered after Job B is completed and similarly Job F is triggered after Job C is completed. and Job G is to be triggered after Job F & Job E are completed.

I notice that Job G is triggered twice after completion of each of the dependent jobs (Job F, Job E). Is there any way I can ensure that Job G runs only once but after completion of Job F and Job E.

Answer (score 0):

One of the better approaches to CI is developing a build process that mirror's the developer's build-cycle as closely possible. You haven't mentioned any other constraints other than build parallelism, and with that information in mind, I'd recommend pulling the hierarchy that you've created in Hudson and moving it into a ant, nant, msbuild, or other script that can be reasonably run on a developer's work station. Then configure Hudson to use that script as its project script. That doesn't mean you can't have the other project's as independent projects in Hudson, it just means that the final project knows how to build itself from all the others.

Lastly, unless the build is long lived, I can't see an issue with letting Hudson run the job twice.